# Python 3.5 in google colab

Tags: python-3.x, google-colaboratory

I'm runing a python code for deep learning in google colab. Python 3.5 is required for that code. How can I install Python 3.5 version in google colab ?

Comment: File > New Python 3 Notebook?

Comment: I want Python version of 3.5 or above not 2 or 3.

Comment: "3" does not mean "3.0". I commonly means the current stable release of 3.x

Comment: Sub version matters. For example, google AI Platform only supports Python 3.5 as of June 21 2019. The model trained there may have problem if loading on the Python 3.6 environment (e.g., due to existence of Lambda layers).

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me.

```
!apt-get install python3.5
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do `!python3 --version` you can see colab current uses Python 3.6.7 which is "python version of 3.5 or above"

alternatively you can use
 [local](https://research.google.com/colaboratory/local-runtimes.html) runtime, this will allow you to use different versions of python

Answer (score 0):

```
!sudo apt-get install python 3.5
```

execute this code in colab cell. Once you are done restart you colab session.

Comment: Please explain why you think that  `sudo` is needed, in contrast to existing and upvoted answer which seems to disagree.

Answer (score -1):

Installation of Python in colab
1- for installation code

```
!apt-get install python3.9
```

2- for version code

```
!python3.9 --version
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).