# Install Python 3.8 kernel in Google Colaboratory

Tags: jupyter-notebook, kernel, google-colaboratory, python-3.8

I try to install a new Python version (3.8) using conda.

```
!wget -O mini.sh https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-py38_4.8.2-Linux-x86_64.sh
!chmod +x mini.sh
!bash ./mini.sh -b -f -p /usr/local
```

This works fine. I can call `!python script.py` to run a 3.8 version.

So, I try my luck with installing another jupyter kernel with Python 3.8 kernel.

```
!conda install -q -y --prefix /usr/local jupyter
!python -m ipykernel install --name "py38" --user
```

I check that the kernel is installed.

```
!jupyter kernelspec list
```

Then I download the notebook down. Open a text editor to change the kernel specification to

```
"kernelspec": {
  "name": "py38",
  "display_name": "Python 3.8"
}
```

This is the same trick that works before, with Javascript, Java, and Golang.

I then upload the edited notebook to Google Drive. Open the notebook in Google Colab. It cannot find the py38 kernel, so it use normal python3 kernel. I run all these cell again.

```
!wget -O mini.sh https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-py38_4.8.2-Linux-x86_64.sh
!chmod +x mini.sh
!bash ./mini.sh -b -f -p /usr/local
!conda install -q -y --prefix /usr/local jupyter
!python -m ipykernel install --name "py38" --user
```

It install the Python 3.8 kernel like before. I refresh the browser, to let it connect to the new kernel, hoping it to work like JavaScript, Java, Golang kernel before.

It doesn't work. It cannot connect. Here's [the notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1ZBHu42_JUSxb7Wt9EBd_qgKqph8o6qXj)

Any help would be appreciated.

## Update (Oct 2022)

Using @ngrislain's method, here's a [notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/12Uy1fTJy4XQDMdXVM_5XJ0iGEdCDOgYf) for Python 3.10 (3.11 also [available](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/13C50iNZRjMRyepe_3xAtMKUQdIkKK0kS))

Comment: This is how it works with ijavascript https://colab.research.google.com/gist/korakot/22abd6eccac229e9cb9a027b088b50d6/notebook.ipynb

Comment: This is how it works with Java https://colab.research.google.com/github/vistec-AI/colab/blob/master/ijava.ipynb

Comment: This is Golang. https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1-6XkA5OhEA6lMW9DvH4_AcXndC7WppJx

Comment: What about for python 3.9? See issue in kora: https://github.com/korakot/kora/issues/21

Comment: fyi, one of the suggested answers is not working anymore, see this SO to hopefully solve it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69487937/python-3-8-with-kora-in-colab-is-not-working-anymore-how-to-fix

Comment: There is a solution that does not require a local kernel or ngrok. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71511943/1854249

Comment: I wouldn't recommend running a third-party shell containing a binary by any means.

Comment: @finiteautomata True indeed. I also provide the `construct.yaml` file, so you can create the binary yourself to be safe. Sometimes, people will opt for convenience at any price, so I provide the binary for maximum convenience.

Comment: @korakot that's great to know! No hard feelings, my remark is only general and not a doubt of your good faith.

Comment: Currently it doesnt seem to work - colab gives the error `Unrecognized runtime "py310"; defaulting to "python3" Notebook settings`and switches to python 3.8.

Comment: That’s correct. You then install py310 runtime then reload to make it works.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For `ipykernel` to work in a colab notebook you need the `google-colab` package to be installed. If not it silently fails (you can notice the problem by running `!python -m ipykernel_launcher`).

Simply add the line `!conda install -q -y google-colab -c conda-forge` and it should work.

```
!wget -O mini.sh https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-py38_4.8.2-Linux-x86_64.sh
!chmod +x mini.sh
!bash ./mini.sh -b -f -p /usr/local
!conda install -q -y jupyter
!conda install -q -y google-colab -c conda-forge
!python -m ipykernel install --name "py38" --user
```

You can test this solution in this fixed [notebook](https://gist.github.com/ngrislain/c3ba6f687c64ce31adc6b0dff1b26d6a)

Don't forget to reload the browser page after you installed the kernel (as explained in the original post).

Comment: This is not working for me. Current version still returns "3.7.12".

Comment: You need to reload the browser page after you installed the kernel.

Comment: Several packages appear with `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named *package x* ` after pip installing them with this method. 

zarr, rasterio, rasterio.features, rioxarray as rio, contextily as cx, stackstac to name a few.

Comment: To those who read the answer and not the question (like me): this solution only works with an **edited notebook**. Simply copying and executing this code will install a new python (`!python -V` returns 3.8.1), but **will not** change the notebook's runtime (`import sys; sys.version` returns 3.7.13).

Comment: @paperskilltrees yes, I exactly have the same problem. But what does mean *edited notebook*? How to make `import sys; sys.version` equals 3.8 with the code above from @ngrislain? Maybe I need make Colab Pro?

Comment: @sirjay Please read the OP's question:
> Then I download the notebook down. Open a text editor to change the kernel specification to

Comment: Works perfectly. Quick check with `!python3 --version` generates `Python 3.8.1`.

Comment: Does this still work with the edited notebook ? I gave it a shot, to no avail though

Comment: @Elle No, it doesn't. For now, to run Python 3.10 in a new notebook, check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/74243532/9303470

Comment: @ngrislain thanks a lot! do you know how to turn on the syntax highlighting?

Answer (score 38):

I have found how to run Python 3.8 notebook on Colab.

- install Anaconda3
- add (fake) google.colab library
- start jupyterlab
- access it with ngrok

Here's the code

```py
# install Anaconda3
!wget -qO ac.sh https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/Anaconda3-2020.07-Linux-x86_64.sh 
!bash ./ac.sh -b

# a fake google.colab library
!ln -s /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/google \
       /root/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google

# start jupyterlab, which now has Python3 = 3.8
!nohup /root/anaconda3/bin/jupyter-lab --ip=0.0.0.0&

# access through ngrok, click the link
!pip install pyngrok -q
from pyngrok import ngrok
print(ngrok.connect(8888))
```

Comment: thats the greatest achievement in the history of mankind :) Thanks so much

Comment: but I can't import libraries, `import boto3` gives error module not found

Comment: did you try appending the python3.6 packages path? `sys.path.append('/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages')`. Not sure if its the proper way but it worked for me

Comment: `!/root/anaconda3/bin/pip install boto3` this works too

Comment: `os.environ['PATH'] = '/root/anaconda3/bin:' + os.environ['PATH']` will add the new pip and conda path to your jupyter notebook environment

Comment: @korakot Just following your recipe, not only can I SSH from my local VS Code into Colab that has Python 3.8 but also the Python 3.8 Jupyter server setting on Colab is ready for use automatically. Thanks for the brilliant solution. I have a question: I tried to modify one step of your recipe by replacing `install Anaconda3` with `install miniconda3` and executing `conda install Jupyter` manually. I found the VS Code no longer detects the Jupyter server. Do you know how to fix this problem?

Comment: @Li-PinJuan I tried miniconda at first and failed too. That's why I use Anaconda that somehow config Jupyter correctly. Hope that one day, we will find how to use the smaller miniconda.

Comment: @korakot does this still work? I'm not able to run kernels via Python 3 with this method. I tried running `jupyter-lab` without nohup to inspect error messages — seems something doesn't work anymore: `'google.colab._kernel.Kernel' could not be imported`

Comment: what about for python 3.9?

Comment: Hi @korakot

This doesn't seem to work the way it should

I got this thrown at me :

The connection to http://44ee-xx-xxx-xx-xxx.ngrok.io/ was successfully tunneled to your ngrok client, 
but the client failed to establish a connection to the local address [localhost:8000](http://localhost:8000/).

Make sure that a web service is running on [localhost:8000](http://localhost:8000/) and that it is a valid address.

The error encountered was: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8000: connect: connection refused

Comment: You don't need ngrok actually, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71511943/1854249

Answer (score 20):

we can also use kora [pip library](https://github.com/airesearch-in-th/kora)

```py
!pip install kora
import kora.install.py38
```

Comment: not sure if im giving you enough credit @korakot. You are kind enough to make the library

Comment: Now in kora 0.6.6, it adds `/root/anaconda3/bin` to PATH for every new notebook. You can now use `pip` correctly.

Comment: Hey korakot, is there any documentation for using kora?

Comment: I get `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/google' -> '/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google'`

Comment: I am also getting: FileExistsError: [Errno 17] File exists: '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/google' -> '/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google'

Comment: what about for python 3.9?

Comment: btw, this didn't actually work for me `JSONDecodeError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-92b8be0c7a4b> in <module>()
      1 get_ipython().system('pip install kora')
----> 2 import kora.install.py38` Error: `/usr/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py in raw_decode(self, s, idx)
    353             obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
    354         except StopIteration as err:
--> 355             raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
    356         return obj, end

JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)`

Comment: related question si py38 is not working anymore: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69487937/python-3-8-with-kora-in-colab-is-not-working-anymore-how-to-fix

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems the `kora` library is now defunct and does not work as described above. Alas! It was pretty cool.

Comment: How to make it work for python 3.10? Do you think it is possible to make it work with the beta version of Python 3.11 (May-2022)?

Answer (score 4):

**Update: Originally answered on 2020-03-29, but this answer is now outdated, see the answers above.**

Based on these previous answers*, it seems that Google only supports python 2.7 and python 3.6 right now (as of 2020-03-29). However, if you must use python 3.8 you could connect to a local runtime: https://research.google.com/colaboratory/local-runtimes.html

*Previous answers:

- [Use latest Python version on Google Colab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53812508/use-latest-python-version-on-google-colab)
- [How to force google colab to run in particular python version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59788607/how-to-force-google-colab-to-run-in-particular-python-version)
- [Google Colab - Choosing specific Python version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54010692/google-colab-choosing-specific-python-version)
- [Is there a way to use Python 3.5 instead of 3.6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52467489/is-there-a-way-to-use-python-3-5-instead-of-3-6)
- [Python 3.5 in google colab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54994129/python-3-5-in-google-colab)

Comment: Thanks for the info. Hope someday I can fix the kernel code. At least for now I can run Python 3.8 as a script in Colab.

Comment: do you mind sharing how you are able to run the 3.8 as a script?

Comment: Yeah I see how SSH'ing and installing that way, while a hack, can make it possible, albeit Colab will delete the environment every time it reloads. However anything you install appears inside only the direct ssh environment and doesn't appear to make it to the "Kernel" in Colab in the Graphical User Interface, which is what the original question was asking about. More info about SSH: https://imadelhanafi.com/posts/google_colal_server/

Answer (score 3):

Try the following code. None of the above answers worked for me.

```
!sudo apt-get update -y
!sudo apt-get install python3.9
!sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.7 1
!sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.9 2
```

[Source](https://www.buzzphp.com/posts/how-can-i-update-google-colabs-python-version).

Comment: using `!python -V` will return 3.9 version, yet using `from platform import python_version` will still return 3.7

Comment: same for me, after suscessfully running the above, I write `!python --version` and it say it is 3.7 (and it gives me a problem due to defining the type of a variable...

Comment: I don't see this switching the notebook to 3.9 .... you will not get 3.9 in the output of `sys.version` after this would you? which means that your code is not interpreted using a 3.9 interpreter after installing python this way in a colab session. Is there a missing config or step or is it a dead end?

Answer (score 2):

Update: Since [Apr 27, 2023](https://medium.com/google-colab/colab-updated-to-python-3-10-27eb02daa162) Colab's default runtime is Python 3.10.11.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to get any of the above answers to work for me.
So I initially installed conda on colab and through conda I installed ***python 3.8***.

Steps:

1. Install conda ([Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59330876/install-conda-package-to-google-colab))

   ```
   !wget https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-py37_4.8.2-Linux-x86_64.sh

   !chmod +x Miniconda3-py37_4.8.2-Linux-x86_64.sh

   !bash ./Miniconda3-py37_4.8.2-Linux-x86_64.sh -b -f -p /usr/local import sys

   sys.path.append('/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/')
   ```
2. Install *python 3.8*

   ```
   !conda install python=3.8
   ```
3. Check the python version

   ```
   !python --version
   ```

Comment: It hangs on solving environment: `Collecting package metadata ...
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: done
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: | 
`  It might have to do with the fact that I did the previous `!sudo ... install ... ` answer... but I don't really know - would love to if anyone does...

Answer (score -6):

I am a senior Japanese hacker.
I referred to the content of this post because I can't use the assignment expression. We appreciate.
However, I had to install the rich Python packages on Colab with conda each time.
In fact Colab does not utilize anaconda.
So, I pip installed the package on py37's pip list with py38.
Create hundreds of Colab packages with Python3.8 pip, read the archived file > decompress it and install the Python3.8 interpreter, dist-package (/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist -packages), I got 3.8 for both Python in Shell and sys.version in Colab, and I was able to use the default packages.
I've documented it on the GitHub page below.
I posted it if some kind of Japanese quality procedure would be helpful.
The relevant page is below.
https://github.com/engbJapan/Programming/blob/main/Colab2py38/filelocal43ColabStoragePageTrypy38.ipynb
If you have any questions or concerns, please leave a comment.