# Python 3.8 with Kora in Colab is not working anymore, how to fix?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, kora

I did:

```
!pip install kora
import kora.install.py38
```

but got error:

```
Requirement already satisfied: kora in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (0.9.19)
Requirement already satisfied: ipython in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from kora) (5.5.0)
Requirement already satisfied: fastcore in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from kora) (1.3.26)
Requirement already satisfied: packaging in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from fastcore->kora) (21.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pip in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from fastcore->kora) (21.1.3)
Requirement already satisfied: simplegeneric>0.8 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from ipython->kora) (0.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pygments in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from ipython->kora) (2.6.1)
Requirement already satisfied: traitlets>=4.2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from ipython->kora) (5.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pickleshare in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from ipython->kora) (0.7.5)
Requirement already satisfied: pexpect in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from ipython->kora) (4.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: prompt-toolkit<2.0.0,>=1.0.4 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from ipython->kora) (1.0.18)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>=18.5 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from ipython->kora) (57.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: decorator in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from ipython->kora) (4.4.2)
Requirement already satisfied: wcwidth in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from prompt-toolkit<2.0.0,>=1.0.4->ipython->kora) (0.2.5)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.9.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from prompt-toolkit<2.0.0,>=1.0.4->ipython->kora) (1.15.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing>=2.0.2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from packaging->fastcore->kora) (2.4.7)
Requirement already satisfied: ptyprocess>=0.5 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from pexpect->ipython->kora) (0.7.0)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
JSONDecodeError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-92b8be0c7a4b> in <module>()
      1 get_ipython().system('pip install kora')
----> 2 import kora.install.py38

5 frames
/usr/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py in raw_decode(self, s, idx)
    353             obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
    354         except StopIteration as err:
--> 355             raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
    356         return obj, end

JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

how do I fix it?

colab link: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1GrhWrWFPmlc6kmxc0TJY0Nb6qOBBgjzX?usp=sharing

related issues:

- https://github.com/korakot/kora/issues/20
- https://github.com/korakot/kora/issues/21

---

ideally 3.9 working in colab would be best: [Install Python 3.8 kernel in Google Colaboratory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60775160/install-python-3-8-kernel-in-google-colaboratory), https://github.com/korakot/kora/issues/21

Answer (score 2):

I'll fix it one day.

For now, you can use this notebook for Python 3.10

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/12Uy1fTJy4XQDMdXVM_5XJ0iGEdCDOgYf