# Deepspeech module not found while running on google colab

Tags: python, pip, speech-to-text

İ need to install Deepspeech 0.6.1 to my system for an Automatic speech recognition project. So as per my mentor's guidance İ used all these codes

[
!pip install deepspeech==0.6.1
!apt-get install -qq sox
import deepspeech

error: ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
 in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 import deepspeech

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'deepspeech']

on Google Collab but when i run 'import deepspeech' code it says module not found.

İ tried these codes next on guidance of a senior.
[
!pip list | grep deepspeech
it showed: deepspeech                         0.6.1 ]

so deepspeech is present but still 'import deepspeech' not working

i have also tried other deepspeech versions like 0.9.3 version but same problem persists

I'm new to python and Google Collab. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

I tried installing `deepspeech` on Google Colab myself. This is the output of `!pip install deepspeech`:

```bash
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement deepspeech (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for deepspeech
```

As the version of installed python on Google colab is 3.10, it looks like there is no available wheel of deepspeech for python 3.10.
it's mentioned here too:

https://github.com/mozilla/DeepSpeech/issues/3694

So you have two options:

1. Downgrading Google Colab's python from 3.10 to 3.9 or lower versions https://stackoverflow.com/a/71511943
2. Using newer Speech to Text libraries, for example https://github.com/openai/whisper or https://github.com/coqui-ai/stt